# missing menubars in all applications Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, display, window, menu-bar

Recently, all the top menubars in all applications have disappeared. Below are examples from Konsole and Libreoffice; the same absence of the top menubar appears in all applications without any exceptions yet discovered.

[image: Konsole screenshot]

[image: Libreoffice screenshot]

This behavior started after I had used a HDMI adapter to project in a room; the projection required a lower resolution than I normally use on the laptop. When I disconnected and restored the usual display resolution, all the menubars were missing.

This hasn't been a serious problem yet... but it will be soon. Any thoughts/guidance would be greatly appreciated - I've been scanning other posts without any similar behavior correspondence.

Comment: It seems that you are using Kubuntu, not Ubuntu. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with **most applications** in Ubuntu 22.04! Except that all I did was to shutdown for the night, then when I booted the next day the menus were gone!

As I have another machine, running Ubuntu 16.04 with the same applications, I was able to check and get the key stroke sequence which then worked, **in some applications**, on the Ubuntu 22.04.

It is never-the-less a pain in the rear bug!

A key stroke sequence is simply the sequence of key strokes to access an item on the menu. i.e Print Preview in Firefox would be Alt-f. v.

But you're missing the point, THE MENUS HAVE DISAPPEARED!

Comment: Can you please be a bit more specific? I can't understand what you mean about the "key stroke sequence".